# The HTTP request to 'http:///xxx.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout

Tags: .net, wcf, http, .net-remoting

I am investigating the following TimeoutException exception. Has anyone encountered this before? Can anyone suggest a solution?

We have a clients that connect to a WCF service to upload a payload of data via HTTP. Recently the server is failing. Here are some exception details:

> mscorlib threw TimeoutException The HTTP request to 'http:///xxx.svc'
>   has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:10. The time allotted to
>   this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action,
>   Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeEndService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type

Please excuse my brevity. I am not a WCF expert. Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Is there a timeout value I can increase?

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the `receiveTimeout` property of your binding.

Here are a couple of links on MSDN:

General: [Configuring Services Using Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx)

Bindings: [Configuring Bindings for Windows Communication Foundation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733099.aspx)